# How to support dynamically growing list of BusinessEvents

Tags: azure-language-understanding

This applies to LUIS (MS Language Understanding)

Want to handle an utterance in the following format

"I met [a-PersonName] at [a-BusinessEvent] in [a-TimeReference]"

Sample utterances might be

- I met Jane Allan at the **Product Management Meetup** in January
- I met James at **MS BUild** in April 2017
- I met Lily Tomlin at **Learning UX Meeting** in June 2018

The challenge is that [a-BusinessEvent] (the bold bits) will grow over time. Sure there are a couple of recurring things such as MSBuild or Apple WWDC but over time I'll want to have the users extend the list of BusinessEvents available. (imagine having a voice interface that would allow 'add new event called **seattle chatbot meetup**').

Should this be a list? or something else?

Are there any examples I could learn from?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your query right, you are looking to have potentially a free form event names and you would want the ability to extract the event name entity out of the utterance consistently.

If my above understanding is right, you might want to take a look at "Pattern.Any" entity. This gives you an ability to extract data from the utterance where the utterances are well-formatted and where the end of the data may be easily confused with the remaining words of the utterance.

Once pattern.any is established, you'll have to add patterns that use the Pattern.any that you have created in order to improve the accuracy.

Visit this documentation for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern-any

For eg., in your case,

- I met Jane Allan at the "pattern.any" in January
- I met James at "pattern.any" in April 2017
- I met Lily Tomlin at "pattern.any" in June 2018

And finally, create a few patterns to improve accuracy.

- I met {PersonName} at the {EventName} in {DateTime}
- I met {PersonName} at {EventName} in {DateTime}
- I met {PersonName} at {EventName} in {DateTime}

Comment: This is very helpful. While it doesn't directly answer my original question, it helps me rethink what the question should have been and what approach I might use (including this). Thank you